# Unresolved reference to symbol " " in section 'Fragment'

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I have added InstallDemo.wxs file and copied the code from WixUI_InstallDir src/ext/wixlib/, Then i have added UIRef into product.wxs file after that when i built the solution i got this 50 error "Unresolved reference to symbol 'Dialog:BrowseDlg' in section 'Fragment' so, Help me to resolve this issue.. please tell me how to create a simple dialog screen in 'WIX' please help, Thank you.!

Comment: This page in the manual explains (beyond everything else) how to customize the dialog sequence and insert a new dialog in the flow: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am new to Wix, so i didn't do lot of stuff to complete the process. as per your link.. i come to know to add properties. Thank you..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you referenced the WixUIExtension in your WIX Installation project? You need this to give you the BrowseDialog.

You can find the WixUIExtension.dll file in the `bin` folder of the WiX Toolset installation folder in Program Files.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I added the WixUIExtension reference already. Now i haven't receive any error like Unresolved reference...etc. I missed to add property for dialog control. That's the reason of my error. Thank again.

Comment: Hi, Yes you right, If removed the WixUIExtension, and built the solution, the error i got.. ! Thank U

Comment: @Cegone If this helped you, you should consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added a new wxs file by accident to a WiX project with build action as content rather than Compile; therefore, WiX was not compiling the newly added wxs file since it was being treated as a content file.

Simple solution is to remove and then re-add the new wxs file.

Comment: That was it! Just go to the .wxs file's properties and change its Build Action to Compile.