# Adding a reference to WixUIExtension results in "Unresolved reference to symbol..."

Tags: wix

I have a WIX project that originally was created with WIX version 2, after migrating the project to WIX version 3 I had a lot of unresolved reference to symbols like Dialog.CancelDlg, Dialog.BrowseDlg, etc...

If I add the [reference to WixUIExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000022/unresolved-reference-to-symbol-in-section-fragment) these symbols resolves, but I get another unresolved symbols in WixUIExtension itself:

**Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:WixAppFolder' in section 'Fragment:' in [UIExtension\wixlib\InstallScopeDlg.wxs](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/InstallScopeDlg.wxs)**

**Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:ApplicationFolderName' in section 'Fragment: in UIExtension\wixlib\WixUI_Advanced.wxs**

I tried to add the references to all available extensions, but this did not help.

While writing this post, an idea came to me: probably I should define them by myself somehow?

Answer (score 4):

solved by adding this:

```
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="My Application Folder" />
<Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />
```