# How to add shortcut to Windows app from jpackage+wix?

Tags: java, windows, wix, cygwin

I got a script (just a simplified excerpt for brevity) to build and package my app, but it boils down to generating WiX installer with:

```sh
jpackage \
    --type msi \
    --dest "$(cygpath -w "${base[build:dist]}")" \
    --name "${appDisplayName}" \
    --app-version "${version}" \
    --app-image "$(cygpath -w "${base[build:app]}")" \
    --license-file "$(cygpath -w resources/app/legal/LICENSE)" \
    --vendor "${vendor}" \
    --verbose \
    --temp 'W:\_tmp_' \
    --win-shortcut;
```

It fails with enigmatic: `Command [light.exe, (...)] in (...) exited with 94 code`. Which I found is about unresolved reference and particularly a reference to a shortcut icon: `...\config\bundle.wxf(10) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Icon:icon1798580986' in section 'Fragment:'`.

When I examined generated WiX XML, I found this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Fragment>
  ...
  <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component Win64="yes" Id="cshortcut9906e12cdacb303ebb5e48c888cf6949" Guid="{9906e12c-dacb-303e-bb5e-48c888cf6949}">
      ...
      <Shortcut Id="shortcut9906e12cdacb303ebb5e48c888cf6949" Name="..." WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Advertise="no" IconIndex="0" Target="[#filed2065cdc42e13
55f8bdbbefc93d540f3]" Icon="icon1798580986"></Shortcut>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  ...
</Wix>
```

And indeed there's this "icon1798580986" value, which does not tell me anything and even WiX is lost here (after reading this this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21019152/2024692 I checked and confirmed that I actually do have `WixUIExtension.dll` in WiX `bin` folder).

When I remove `--win-shortcut` option, then MSI installer is generated, but unfortunately w/o shortcut icon on the desktop (the app has it's proper icons, thou, as I generated application image with `--icon` switch and with `--resource-dir` pointing to a.o. app icons).

As you probably guessed, this is called from Cygwin, so sometimes it needs fiddling with paths, especially when one calls Windows executables (hence these `cygpath` things).

Well, I wasn't able to find any constructive approaches how to simply allow my Java application packed with `jpackage` (from both JDK-14/15 EA with no success) to have nice shortcut icon after it gets installed. Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution for incorporating the icon? I just gave up creating a desktop shortcut.

Comment: @DavidCian Unfortunately not yet. I was hoping to run postinstall script (the shortcut can be created via batch script), but it seems, like postinstall works on macOS and Linux, but not on Windows (at least I was not able to run it on Windows). If you, on the other hand, managed to run postinstall script on Windows, then I would happily share the code (but I suppose, you would figure it out instantly by your own means).

Answer (score 3):

its easier to do with a gradle plugin

You need to set the proper icon file path and have a valid .ico file. This is how I did it:

```
jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'PDF Decorator'
        jvmArgs = ['-Djdk.gtk.version=2'] // required due to a bug in Java: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/175
    }
    jpackage {
        installerOptions = [
            '--description', project.description,
            '--copyright', 'Copyrigth 2015-2019 WALCZAK.IT'
        ]
        installerType = project.findProperty('installerType') // we will pass this from the command line (example: -PinstallerType=msi)
        if (installerType == 'msi') {
            imageOptions += ['--icon', 'src/main/resources/pdfdecorator/gui/icon.ico']
            installerOptions += [
                '--win-per-user-install', '--win-dir-chooser',
                '--win-menu', '--win-shortcut'
            ]
        }
        if (installerType == 'pkg') {
            imageOptions += ['--icon', 'src/main/resources/pdfdecorator/gui/icon.icns']
        }
        if (installerType in ['deb', 'rpm']) {
            imageOptions += ['--icon', 'src/main/resources/pdfdecorator/gui/icon_256x256.png']
            installerOptions += [
                '--linux-menu-group', 'Office',
                '--linux-shortcut'
            ]
        }
        if (installerType == 'deb') {
            installerOptions += [
                '--linux-deb-maintainer', 'office@walczak.it'
            ]
        }
        if (installerType == 'rpm') {
            installerOptions += [
                '--linux-rpm-license-type', 'GPLv3'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## If error 94 happens without `--win-shortcut`

This might actually be a problem relating to the `--app-image` parameter given to jpackage! An indicator for that is the **warning that the app-image wasn't created by jpackage.**

If your destination parameter when creating the app-image looks like `--dest target/app-image`, then you have to use `--app-image target/app-image/myapp` when creating the installer. Using `--app-image target/app-image` results in this error. A minor oversight that can create a lot of head-scratching because of the cryptic message.

This seems to happen for the reason @Mumrah81 gave:

> [...] jpackage expect to find the executable and the icon at the root of app-image directory to create the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You just had the pleasure given by convention over configuration

When using jpackage `--app-image` and `--win-shorcut` parameters then jpackage expect to find the executable and the icon at the root of app-image directory to create the shortcut. The executable and the icon must have the same name as the one provided using the `--name` parameter.

In your case jpackage expects:

```
$(cygpath -w "${base[build:app]}")\${appDisplayName}.exe
$(cygpath -w "${base[build:app]}")\${appDisplayName}.ico
```

to exists to be able to create the shortcut.

Comment: Did not tested that yet — `jpackage` from JDK 14.0.1 works on previous config as expected, thou.